# Stop ChromeDriver backtrace logs when Selenium tests fail

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, stack-trace

I have issue with to verbose logging by `ChromeDriver`

When selenium test fail, beside standard error logs in terminal I get backtrace messages like:

```
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00B378B3+2193587]
    Ordinal0 [0x00AD0681+1771137]
    Ordinal0 [0x009E41A8+803240]
    ...
```

How to disable this backtrace? (best in Python :)

**My setup:**

```
Windows 10    
Python 3.8.3    
Selenium 4.4.3    
Chrome: 105.0.5195.127 
ChromeDriver: 105.0.5195.52
```

I read already below discussion but no clear answer found:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9977
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3944

**Options checked:**

```
   service.log_file = -1
   opts.add_argument('--incognito')
   opts.add_argument('--log-level=0')
   opts.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
   driver = Chrome(service=service, options=opts, service_log_path='NUL')
```

**Example code**

```
from unittest import TestCase

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class SelBacktrace(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        service.log_file = -1
        opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        opts.add_argument("--log-level=0")
        opts.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=opts, service_log_path='NUL')
        self.driver.get('https://httpbin.org/anything/')

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_backtrace(self):
        element_located = expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.unexisting'))
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1).until(element_located)
```

**Example output**

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\backtrace\test.py", line 27, in test_backtrace
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 1).until(element_located)
  File "C:\backtrace\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 90, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x0023DF13+2219795]
    Ordinal0 [0x001D2841+1779777]
    Ordinal0 [0x000E423D+803389]
    Ordinal0 [0x00113025+995365]
    Ordinal0 [0x001131EB+995819]
    Ordinal0 [0x00140F52+1183570]
    Ordinal0 [0x0012E844+1108036]
    Ordinal0 [0x0013F192+1175954]
    Ordinal0 [0x0012E616+1107478]
    Ordinal0 [0x00107F89+950153]
    Ordinal0 [0x00108F56+954198]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00532CB2+3040210]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00522BB4+2974420]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x002D6A0A+565546]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x002D5680+560544]
    Ordinal0 [0x001D9A5C+1808988]
    Ordinal0 [0x001DE3A8+1827752]
    Ordinal0 [0x001DE495+1827989]
    Ordinal0 [0x001E80A4+1867940]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75CE6739+25]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x772990AF+1215]
    RtlGetFullPathName_UEx [0x7729907D+1165]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]





Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap basic selenium calls with cleaner error output. Here's a full example you can run with `pytest` or `pythom -m unittest` (I named the file `refined_raw.py`):

```py
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from unittest import TestCase


class RefinedRawSelenium(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = None
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
        if "linux" in sys.platform:
            options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_experimental_option(
            "excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation", "enable-logging"],
        )
        prefs = {
            "credentials_enable_service": False,
            "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
        }
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    def tearDown(self):
        if self.driver:
            try:
                if self.driver.service.process:
                    self.driver.quit()
            except Exception:
                pass

    def wait_for_element_visible(
        self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=5
    ):
        try:
            return WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, selector))
            )
        except Exception:
            raise Exception(
                "Selector {%s} was not visible after %s seconds!"
                % (selector, timeout)
            )

    def open(self, url):
        self.driver.get(url)

    def click(self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=5):
        el = self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        el.click()

    def type(self, selector, text, by="css selector", timeout=5):
        el = self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        el.clear()
        if not text.endswith("\n"):
            el.send_keys(text)
        else:
            el.send_keys(text[:-1])
            el.submit()

    def assert_element(self, selector, by="css selector", timeout=5):
        self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)

    def assert_text(self, text, selector="html", by="css selector", timeout=5):
        el = self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        self.assertIn(text, el.text)

    def assert_exact_text(self, text, selector, by="css selector", timeout=5):
        el = self.wait_for_element_visible(selector, by=by, timeout=timeout)
        self.assertEqual(text, el.text)

    def test_add_item_to_cart(self):
        self.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        self.type("#user-name", "standard_user")
        self.type("#password", "secret_sauce\n")
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_text("PRODUCTS", "span.title")
        self.click('button[name*="backpack"]')
        self.click("#shopping_cart_container a")
        self.assert_exact_text("YOUR CART", "span.title")
        self.assert_text("Backpack", "div.cart_item")
        self.click("#react-burger-menu-btn")
        self.click("a#logout_sidebar_link")
        self.assert_element("input#login-button")
```

Here's how it looks when running the test with `pytest`:

```bash
$ pytest refined_raw.py 
======================================= test session starts
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.5, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
collected 1 item                                                                                   

refined_raw.py .

======================================== 1 passed in 4.62s
```

Here's how it looks when running the test with `python -m unittest`:

```bash
$ python -m unittest refined_raw.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 4.199s
OK
```

If you change a selector to be fake so that the test fails on purpose, here's how the output may look:

```
Exception: Selector {fake.element} was not visible after 5 seconds!
```

And before you go out wrapping all your selenium methods to get the desired output seen above, you may want to try https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase , which does all that for you, and more. (Full disclosure, this is a framework that I built over several years for Python and Selenium.)

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately running this code still give me backtrace, see my example in question. (and btw it is honor to get replay from creator of best python selenium framework!)

Comment: Instead of directly calling ``WebDriverWait`` from your tests, use ``wait_for_element_visible()`` as seen from my example, which wraps the ``WebDriverWait`` calls with better error output if those methods fail. You can also wrap ``wait_for_element_visible()`` even more, for methods such as ``click()``, etc.